# iTerm 2 running tmux session causes "startup disk almost full" randomly

Tags: mac, tmux, iterm2

Anytime I run a tmux session, disk space will randomly begin filling up and the computer will slow down, then everything goes back to normal. This happens periodically. I am using iTerm 2.

Does anyone have any way I can debug this?

Comment: Try running lsof and see what files tmux and iterm have open.  Are they opening temp files somewhere?  I use both pretty heavily and haven't run into this.  Are you running released iterm/tmux or did you build your own?